# How can I Change App Edge Lighting Deafult Color

Tags: android, android-layout, colors

How do i change this default color programmatilcaly?

Note: i just started a new project and looked into this option, and this color was there. i've searched in files and cant find where i can change this.
This option is from samsung S8 edge screen settings.

[image]

This is my colors.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#3F51B5</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#303F9F</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#FF4081</color>


</resources>
```

And this is styles.xml

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

    </style>

</resources>
```

Comment: What is this "other app"?

Comment: its just my test lol

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but you can't do that, at least not without root.

Samsung stores the colors as a JSON asset file as part of the CocktailBarService app. The file is private to that app and can't be modified through normal means.

Comment: But how can i set a color in this case? cause that green is default to when i created my test app.

Comment: I don't know how to set it.